# FormsAuthentication in MVC 4 : Once the user is authenticated login page should not be opened

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, forms-authentication

I implemented `FormsAuthentication` in `MVC4` application.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="1"  />
</authentication>

private void SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                    userName,
                                    DateTime.Now,
                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                                    persistanceFlag, ""
                                    );

            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
        }
```

Also, I can modify `timeout` in case system is idle, page will redirect to login page.

Now what I need is that if the user has successfully logged in then `Login` page should not be opened if user enters the login url in browser.

How to achieve the same ?

Comment: Have you provided default `controller` and `action` in `RouteConfig.cs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your login page, add the following razor code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
}
```

Replace `Index` and `Home` with the action/controller of your choice. This will cause the page to redirect if the user is authenticated.